# How can i parse img tags with k6/loadimpact?

Tags: javascript, parsing, load-testing, k6

i'm using k6 loadtesting for my work now and have a problem. How can i parse  links from site?
(already use official examples for href links, but dont understand how to mutate this to work with images)

for example i'm trying with this site - top-tuning.ru (this is one of examples in my task at work). i need the script to parse img links and hrefs. I'm already trying the official exaples and can parse hrefs, head titles, langAttr, but there is no way for me to do the same with img. this structures works pretty well:

```
const res = http.get("top-tuning.ru/"); 
const doc = parseHTML(res); 
const pageTitle = doc.find('head title').text(); 
const langAttr = doc.find('html').attr('lang');
doc.find("body").toArray().forEach(function (item) {
console.log(item.attr("href"));});
```

Comment: I already answered you in the community forum. 

You need to tell us though what you have tried and what hadn't worked in order to better help you :). 

Here is answer to a fairly close question that will likely help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/61075801/5427244

Comment: i don't understand how to use your script in answer to use it with my site for finding img links

Comment: The script that I linked is going through a lot more then just the images. And it isn't mine.

Can you at least update your question with what you've tried and the page you are trying it with (it might not be your real page, just some public page) so we can better diagnose what exactly isn't working? Also what you used for links will likely help as well

Comment: but every try with images in another code tries gave me the <object object> as result, or <undefined> and <>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following script I get your images:

```js
import http from "k6/http";
import { parseHTML } from "k6/html";

export default function() {
    const res = http.get("https://top-tuning.ru/"); 
    const doc = parseHTML(res.body); 
    const pageTitle = doc.find('head title').text(); 
    const langAttr = doc.find('html').attr('lang');
    doc.find("img").toArray().forEach(function (idx) {
        console.log(idx.attr("src"));
    });
}
```

The import parts that I need to change are:

1. you need protocol (https in this case) to make the request
2. you need to provide the body not the response object to parseHTML

After that - everything worked :)

I hope this helps you, you can also use `console.log`, `Object.keys(object)` and `JSON.stringify(object)` when you don't know what is happening